# Missing \endcsname in xparse

Tags: luatex, xparse, csquotes

I am trying to make my own class, with options for referencing. Short quotes work absolutely fine, but when it gets to longer quotes, for some reason, I get errors.

essay.tex:

```
\documentclass[bib]{CallymArticle}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}
\quote{blah blah short}{CreationUnderCapitalism}
\quote{\lipsum[3]}{CreationUnderCapitalism}
\end{document}
```

CallymArticle.cls:

```
\NeedsTeXFormat{LaTeX2e}
\ProvidesClass{CallymArticle}

\LoadClass[12pt,a4paper,british]{article}
\RequirePackage{etoolbox}
\RequirePackage{xparse}

\newcommand{\setOption}[1]{\newtoggle{#1}\DeclareOption{#1}{\settoggle{#1}{true}}}

\setOption{bib}

\ProcessOptions\relax

% font stuff
\RequirePackage[british]{babel}

% quoting
\RequirePackage{csquotes}
\iftoggle{bib}{
    \RequirePackage[notes,backend=biber]{biblatex-chicago}
    \addbibresource{refs.bib}
    \SetCiteCommand{\autocite}
    \RenewDocumentCommand{\quote}{+m g}{\blockcquote{#2}{#1}}
}{
    \RenewDocumentCommand{\quote}{+m g}{\blockquote{#1}}
}
\endinput
```

I am trying to make it so I can write quotes like \quote{text}{optional citation}, in a format that will work with and without the bib option, which requires me to re-order the arguments to \blockcquote.

I get these errors, all on line 7.

```
Missing \endcsname inserted.
Package etoolbox Error: Toggle '\endgraf' undefined.
Missing \endcsname inserted.
Package etoolbox Error: Toggle '\textquoteright \let \textquoteleft \textquot.
Missing } inserted.
```

The output is

[image: output pdf]

Comment: By longer quotes you mean "text with paragraphs". `\blockquote` is not equipped for that. You'll have to use something like the `displayquote` environment. It also makes sense that paragraph-style quotes be displayed rather than inline.

Comment: The simple `\blockcquote{abc}{def\par ghi}` shows that the problem is in `\blockcquote` not accepting `\par` in its second argument. It doesn't help if you declare argument `#1` of `\quote` as long with `+`. By the way, I don't see why declaring the second argument with `g`, as it seems mandatory.

Comment: It works absolutely fine with the same document when I use \blockcquote. I'm trying to make it switch between referencing and not referencing using just one style.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I fixed the above issue by changing

```
\RenewDocumentCommand{\quote}
```

to

```
\NewDocumentCommand{\cquote}
```

I think csquotes was using \quote somewhere behind the scenes, so me redefining it was breaking stuff.